# Visual Studio Code includePath subdirectories

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm struggling with the includePath setting on a bigger project source.
Let's say I have a folder structure like:

```
/BaseComponent/public
/BaseComponent/include
/BaseComponent/source
/SubComponent1/public
/SubComponent1/include
/SubComponent1/source
/SubComponent1/SubSubComponent/public
/SubComponent1/SubSubComponent/include
/SubComponent1/SubSubComponent/source
/SubComponent2/public
/SubComponent2/include
/SubComponent2/source
```

I tried to do a configuration like this:

```
"includePath": [
    ...
    "${workspaceRoot}",
    "${workspaceRoot}/*/include",
     "${workspaceRoot}/*/public"
],
```

But this didn't appear to work out. Is there a way to have just all header inside the workspaceRoot used? Something like "include all subfolder"?

OR another way to define a path which is project in dependend?

Comment: Assuming that all these folders are subdirectories of your working space, this should work  "${workspaceFolder}/**"  . Let me know if that doesn't solve your issue

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
"${workspaceFolder}/**"
```

Assuming all the dirs are inside your working space folder.

Comment: This feature was added on [26 Jun 2018](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/723#event-1702373896)

Answer (score 1):

June 2023: this is supported, as detailed in "[how to include all child folders with specific folder name as include path in VSCode C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988044/6309)".

[`microsoft/vscode-cpptools` PR 10388](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/pull/10388): "**Add wildcard support for `includeDir`**" implements this.

---

Oct. 2018: <del>That is not yet possible/supported</del>, as mentioned in [`Microsoft/vscode-cpptools` issue 849](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/849).
Example of a context illustrating that issue:

> The `includePath` doesn't seem to work with NuGet packages since the directory name includes the version.
> For example, if we use `package rapidjson 1.0.`2 and later upgrade, we'd have to update references to "`packages/rapidjson.1.0.2/build/native/include`" in this file - in additional to any `packages.config` files.
> **It would be nice if we could use wildcards in directory specifiers or some other means of not having to maintain the same information in two different places**.

So the alternative is to version a script able to generate the configuration file by updating the `IncludePath` section with all include folders found.

---

Note: [issue 849](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/849) is actually a duplicate of [issue 723](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/723), which states ([Bob Brown, from Microsoft](https://github.com/bobbrow)):

> A middle wildcard is not currently supported.
>
> **[I started a branch that would support this a while ago](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/tree/bobbrow/expand-wildcards)**, but I forget what state it was in and now the branch is out of date.
> If anyone wants to get it back in sync with master and finish it, we can consider taking it.
> I'll reopen this issue since the original request was not actually addressed.