# how to include all child folders with specific folder name as include path in VSCode c++

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

This is my folder struct:

```
Root/
├─ FolderA/
│  ├─ public/
├─ FolderB/
│  ├─ FolderBB/
│  │  ├─ public/
├─ FolderC/
│  ├─ public/
```

I would like to add all **public** folders to the include path, something like `\w*\/*\w*/public`

Comment: you have to add each folder with its own `-I` argument, C++ compilers don't allow wildcards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like VScode cpp plugin does not support this.  There is an issue related to this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/723

Comment: It is supported now. See [my edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988044/6309).

Answer (score 1):

Jan. 2023: [Rémy F.](https://github.com/yne) proposes (Jan. 2023) a possible option in [`microsoft/vscode-cpptools` issue 723](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/723#issuecomment-1369098032):

> Here is a standalone working example of a glob walker

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import process from 'process'
class Demo {
    globMatch(pattern, str) {// use picomatch ?
        let i = 0;
        let j = 0;
        while (i < pattern.length && j < str.length) {
            if (pattern.charAt(i) == '*') {
                if (i + 1 == pattern.length)
                    return true;
                for (let k = j; k < str.length; k++)
                    if (this.globMatch(pattern.substring(i + 1), str.substring(k)))
                        return true;
                return false;
            } else {
                if (pattern.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j))
                    return false;
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        return (i == pattern.length && j == str.length);
    }
    tryReadDir = (dir) => { try { const res = fs.readdirSync(dir); return res; } catch (e) { return []; } };
    globWalkDir(components, i = 0) {
        if (i >= components.length || components[i] == '**') {
            return path.sep + components.join(path.sep); // end of expression
        }
        const cwd = path.sep + components.slice(0, i).join(path.sep);
        return this.tryReadDir(cwd)
            .filter(name => this.globMatch(components[i], name))
            .filter(match => fs.lstatSync(path.join(cwd, match)).isDirectory())
            .map(match => this.globWalkDir([...components.slice(0, i), match, ...components.slice(i + 1)], i + 1));
        //console.log({components,i, cwd, ls, res})
    }
}

if (!process.argv[2] || !path.isAbsolute(process.argv[2])) {
    throw 'USAGE: glob.mjs ABS_GLOB_EXP';
}
const compo = process.argv[2].split(path.sep).slice(1);

console.log(new Demo().globWalkDir(compo).flat(compo.length));
```

> It allow partial matching, for example :
>
> ```bash
> > globWalkDir(['usr','l*','**']); // "/usr/l*/**" pattern
> [ '/usr/lib/**', '/usr/lib32/**', '/usr/local/**' ]
> ```
>
> and can be used as drop-in replacement of `resolveAndSplit()` in `~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-*/dist/main.js`.

---

June 2023: this is now implemented with [`microsoft/vscode-cpptools` PR 10388](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/pull/10388): "**Add wildcard support for `includeDir`**"

> For example, using the following tree:
>
> ```
>  rootUri
>  - sources
>    - main
>      - main.c
>    - vendor
>      - khash.h
>  - headers
>    - C001
>      - a.h
>    - C002
>      - b.h
> ```
>
> The following directory paths works:
>
> - `sources/**`  for plain old recursive path
> - `headers/C*/` dynamic path
> - `missing/`    reported as "not found"
> - `missing/*`   expanded as empty result (silent fail)
>
> Note: bakslash paths need to be slash-converted to avoid be considered as "Dynamic"